# Hide keyboard key (bottom right key) is not working when we use inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, keyboard

I am working on an iPad application which uses bluetooth bar code scanner. I am connecting the scanner as using HID Profile and it is treated as a bluetooth keyboard by iPad. When scanner is connected to iPad using bluetooth and if we focus on any text field inside application, it won't open device virtual keyboard. This is expected as device treats bar code scanner as bluetooth keyboard.

For showing device virtual keyboard for some text fields which are used for manual entry, we are using inputAccessoryView. This works fine but when device is connected to bluetooth keyboard, bottom right side key in the keyboard(which is for hiding the keyboard) doesn't work. I am able to hide keyboard when we click on "Return" key and even when we click anywhere outside in the screen. I am not sure whether we get the click event of this hide keyboard key.

Please let us know if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following method. don't forget add delegate to keyboard UITextFieldDelegate

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}



-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*) textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. textFieldShouldReturn was already there and it was working. Keyboard was getting hidden when we click on "return" key. Now I added  touchesBegan and still hide key click is not working.

Comment: did you use textFieldShouldEndEditing ??

Comment: Try this - (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}

Comment: I just tried disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal and still not working. I want to add one more observation. When I click on some other key, some times (1 out of 50) the keyboard just moves up a bit. After that if we click on hide key it works. After this I tried moving keyboard up using code but that didn't help.